# Microsoft Graph API and C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I downloaded (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) the Quickstart Microsoft Graph Example for C#.

When I want to start the Programm, the Programm always wants to make a new Authentification to Microsoft Graph via the Web Browser. How can I implement it to do it in the Background or memorize the key?

I have a tenant id, a client id, and a client secret key.

I expected it will only authorize once

Comment: You can use a certificate to authenticate to the Graph API

Comment: Could you share your code? At least the part when you create new Graph service client.

Comment: @user2250152 does not require code sharing. it is a valid question. I was looking for such solution as well.

Comment: what was the solution for it? @MaythamFahmi

Comment: @MaythamFahmi But it requires for others to download the sample code and check if it generates web application or console application, version of Microsoft.Graph NuGet etc. There are breaking changes between Microsoft.Graph v4 and v5. Different libraries for authentication

Comment: That is fair enough. Hope OP updates the question.

Comment: I made a new Topic for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75662376/authenticate-to-microsoft-graph-with-python?noredirect=1#comment133482832_75662376