# Authenticate to Microsoft Graph with Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I downloaded the script from the mcirsoft developer page to get a connection between python and the mcirosoft graph api. This works fine. (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start)

If I start the script I have to authenticate every time. In the Python Console it says following text:

> To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code DY73DDLYA to authenticate.

The Python function for authentication is this:

```
def initialize_graph_for_user_auth(config):
    this.settings = config
    client_id = this.settings['clientId']
    tenant_id = this.settings['authTenant']
    graph_scopes = this.settings['graphUserScopes'].split(' ')

    this.device_code_credential = DeviceCodeCredential(client_id, tenant_id = tenant_id)
    this.user_client = GraphClient(credential=this.device_code_credential, scopes=graph_scopes)
```

How can I authenticate only once?
I have the authentication already in the config file.

```
[azure]
clientId = <CLIENT_ID>
clientSecret = <CLIENT_SECRET>
tenantId = <TENANT_ID>
authTenant = common
graphUserScopes = GroupMember.ReadWrite.All
```

I expected the credentials are enough to authenticate to Azure.

Comment: Did you tried using Client_credentials method from the code snippet that is generated from the link you mentioned?

Comment: Refer here- def ensure_graph_for_app_only_auth():
    if not hasattr(this, 'client_credential'):
        client_id = this.settings['clientId']
        tenant_id = this.settings['tenantId']
        client_secret = this.settings['clientSecret']

        this.client_credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

    if not hasattr(this, 'app_client'):
        this.app_client = GraphClient(credential=this.client_credential,
                                      scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])
# </AppOnyAuthConfigSnippet>

# <GetUsersSnippet>

Comment: I tried this code: def initialize_graph_for_user_auth(config):
    if not hasattr(this, 'client_credential'):
        this.settings = config
        client_id = this.settings['clientId'] ,
        tenant_id = this.['tenantId'] ,
        client_secret = this.settings['clientSecret']
        print(tenant_id)

        this.user_client = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
    if not hasattr(this, 'app_client'):
        this.user_client = GraphClient(credential=this.client_credential, scope=['graph.microsoft.com/.default']) #  But then I get invalid tenant id

Answer (score 1):

you can always use this template to get access token using python.

make sure to install this modules in your system `pip install requests, msal`
Replace `tenantID, clientID and clientsecret with information retrieved from your app registration in azure AD`

```
import msal
import json
import requests


def get_access_token():
    tenantID = 'xxx' #replace with yours
    authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantID
    clientID = 'xxx' # replace with yours
    clientSecret = 'xxx' # replace with yours
    scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID, authority=authority, client_credential = clientSecret)
    access_token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    return access_token

# token block
access_token = get_access_token()
token = access_token['access_token']
print(token)
```

Then you can make API calls likes this

For example to returns all my users using graph api

```
# Construct the URL for the Microsoft Graph API
# return all users in the tenant: 
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"

# Set the headers for the API call
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Send the API request and get the response
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse the response as JSON
data = json.loads(response.text)
print(data)
```

This solution does not require you to always authenticate device etc....I hope it helps.

Comment: You can vote as the correct answer..